# Synchronizing a shared variable among threads in DIFFERENT classes in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

this is for my NXT brick.

Let's say I have two DIFFERENT classes, Class `A` and Class `B`, and each class has its OWN thread running.

However, there is a static variable instance called `MotorA` that is shared by both classes. This `MotorA` variable is a PHYSICAL motor whose motion can be controlled by the two classes. Both Class `A` and Class `B`'s threads can control `MotorA`'s motion but I only want ONE of them to control `MotorA` at a time.

For example, if Class `A` is trying to rotate `MotorA` forward and Class `B` is trying to rotate `MotorA` backward, I only want Class `A` to rotate `MotorA` forward and block Class B's effect.

Question: Can I use the SAME lock to synchronize methods in threads from DIFFERENT classes?

Comment: Yes, you can; each resource should be protected by exactly one lock. (Although it might be better to have a class that encapsulates access to the motor and its lock.)

Comment: As the motor variable is shared between the two threads, `synchronize` on that motor variable, that's perfectly legal.

Comment: while `MotorA` is static, so making method synchronized doesn't help(unless methods is static too), you need to lock the variable inside the method.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. You can actually do it like this:

```
  class MotorA {

    private static MotorA motor = new MotorA(); 
    private static final java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock lock = new java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock();

    private MotorA() { }

    public static MotorA getMotorA() {
    return motor;
    }

    public static Lock getLock() {
    return lock;
    }

    /* here go business methods for MotorA */

 }
```

Next, when you want to do any operation on MotorA instance, you just need:

- 1) retrieve its lock by `getLock()`
- 2) Call Lock.lock() on the given instance
- 3) acquire MotorA singleton by    `getMotorA()`
- 4) perform any    method on `MotorA` instace
- 5) Call       Lock.unlock() to release the    lock.

In this case, the access to the resource will be safe from multiple threads.

Or you can simply synchronize on the instance of MotorA:

```
  class UserOfMotor1 {

    public void doOperationInMotor1Thread() {

        synchronized(MotorA.getMotorA()) {

            MotorA motor = MotorA.getMotorA();
            motor.soSth();

        }
    }

  }
```

But in this case, you will also have to use `synchronized()` block in whenever thread uses the shared resource - in your case `MotorA`. If you use this method of controlling synchronization, you must ensure that you are synchronizing on the same object in different threads - in this case `MotorA` is a `Singleton` so you always get the same instance.

Comment: Thank you very much! May I achieve the same effect by just throwing all my code inside a synchronized(lock){ } instead of doing the lock and unlock thing?

Comment: Yes. But it will be a different mechanism then - but still the same result. You can synchronize() on any object. In your case, it would be easier to synchronize on MotorA instance. Lock.lock() is a different mechanism from synchronized(), even though doing the same in most cases. It is just a matter of preference which one to use, even though Lock is more flexible in case you have multiple synchronized blocks.

Comment: Hi there, I still don't quite get the difference betweeen synchronized(this) and synchronized(MotorA). What difference would it make to use a dummy object as the synchronized lock as opposed to using the actual object I want exclusive access to? Thank you!

Comment: this keyword means that you refer to the object, from which the method is called. If you refer to "this" inside MotorA class, you will synchronize the same as on "MotorA". You CAN use a dummy object. There are many ways. But you need to synchronized on this dummy object in all threads where you use MotorA then. It is just the matter of choice. I just wrote an example.

Comment: Also, I would like to ask: if I want Class B to override Class A's control, what should I do? For example, Class A thread rotates motor forward continuously, Class B has a method that rotates motor backward. if Class A is currently rotating the motor forward, and I call Class B method, I want the motor to: start rotating the motor backward for a certain period of time, then when this Class B method is done, resume to rotating forward. (give back Class A control of the motor)

Comment: Instead of having to call `getLock()` every time you want to use `MotorA`, why not have the methods that perform an action that needs to be threadsafe handle the locking themselves?

Comment: @user2973438, you can do this with the wait/notify mechanism. It is a topic for one more question, though.

Comment: @SpacePope, I think his method are long-running. If that is the case, from my point of view it is easier to synchronize on them from the outside. Still it can be done maybe like you mentioned. But the OP asked, if it is possible to synchronize on 1 lock from 2 threads.

Comment: Well, technically the same lock would be used my way too - there would only be one instance of the lock object, held by the singleton `MotorA`. I was just looking to cut down on code duplication and having to remember to always call `getLock()` before running the method itself. Is the lock be held for a shorter amount of time if the locking's done externally?

Comment: @SpacePope, no + calling getLock() itself has some impact, but it is really minor. But synchronization from the outside also allows you to hold the lock for the span of multiple operations on the MotorA instance. So, in case OP needs not only to rotate the motor, but also to set its speed in a transactional manner, he would use the external synchronization.

Comment: Good point; I hadn't thought of the potential need to have a series of operations act as a unit. External synchronization would definitely be the way to go in that case.

Comment: @ArtemMoskalev A side question - the class variables MotorA and lock can be declared as `private static final` instead of only `private static`?

Comment: @Prahalad Deshpande, yes. Forgot it - the lock is never changed so yes, it can be final.

Answer (score 2):

Each thread can `synchronize` on the motor instance while its working with it. However, if one thread is going to be using multiple motors together, this would lead you to acquire locks on each motor. Then you'd have to be *very* careful about the order you nest your synchronized blocks, or you will have intermittent **deadlocks.**

Instead, I suggest that you use a single lock for all motors, and never use any motor without holding that lock. Since the motors are static resources, this lock could be too. In a big program, it would be a bit safer to create your own private lock, and carefully control who can access it. In this context, it's probably okay to have a global lock variable that any code can access.

```
final class Locks {

  public static final Object MOTORS = new Object();

  private Locks() { /* Disallow instantiation. */ }

}
```

To use it:

```
final class ThreadA extends Thread {

  public void run() {
    ...
    synchronized(Locks.MOTORS) {
      Motor motorA = Motors.A;
      motorA.setSpeed(...);
      ...
    }
  }

}
```

You wouldn't need to limit yourself to just motors; the key is not to have nested blocks synchronizing on different objects. That might happen directly in one method, or because you call one method with a synchronized block from a synchronized block in another method.

Answer (score 0):

You can write methods in Class `A` and `B` which synchronizes on the mutex called `motor` as below:

```
class A{

public void doSomething(){
    synchronized(MotorA.motor){
        //do what you want
    }
}



class B{

public void doSomething(){
    synchronized(MotorA.motor){
        //do what you want
    }
}
```

Here is the class for `MotorA`

```
class MotorA{
    public static MotorA motor=new MotorA();
    ......
    ......
    ......
}
```

**EDIT**

If you already have a instance and want to share among class `A` and `B` than you can pass the object in constructure and synchronize on the object:

```
class A{
    final MutexObject mm;
    public A(MutexObject m){
        mm=m;
    }
    public void doSomething(){
        synchronized(mm){
            //do what you want
        }
    }



class B{
final MutexObject mm;
public B(MutexObject m){
    mm=m;
}
public void doSomething(){
    synchronized(mm){
        //do what you want
    }
}
```

But be careful while passing the object of `MutexObject` into the constructers of `A` and `B`, it should be same instance.

Comment: Does this work if MotorA is actually an INSTANCE of another class called NXTRegulatedMotor? That class is not invented by me, it comes with leJOS (Java virtual machine for the NXT brick I am trying to program!)

What I mean is this:

NXTRegulatedMotor MotorA = Motor.A;

Comment: It will work, you just need to make sure that you share the same instance among the class `A` and `B`. And synchronize on the same instance. Any thing else you need?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question you asked, just some advice.

I suggest you make your "Motor" a class in itself.  You don't have to give either of your other classes "Control" of the motor variable itself, they just both have references to the motor class.  You can synchronize each method on the motor class so that one method will have control until a sequence of commands is complete, then release control as the method returns.

I've NEVER see more classes (or methods) make code more complex--I've heard it can happen, but I've never seen it.  The complexity I've seen always comes from trying to do things without creating new methods or classes.

The methods on your motor class can make more sense as well.  For instance (Sorry, I have no idea how this works, so I'm just guessing) if you activate the motor by setting a bit, you can expose method like "goForward(int speed)" and "goBack(int speed)" instead of "motor|=0x10" or something obscure like that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of synchronizing at the end user class (ClassA & ClassB), you can do it in your motorA class itself. It should be the MotorA class's responsibility to synchronize its actions.

MotorA class :

```
public class MotorA {

    private static MotorA instance = new MotorA();
    private static int pointer = 0;

    private MotorA() {
    }

    public static MotorA getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }


   public void rotate() {
       synchronized(MotorA.class) {
           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " Rotating "+ pointer++);
           try {
              Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
   }

}
```

End user of the MotorA class - ClassA & ClassB which doesn't know much about the existences of the other threads.

```
public class ClassA implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doRotate();

    }

    private void doRotate() {
        MotorA motor = MotorA.getInstance();
        while (true) {
            motor.rotate();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


public class ClassB implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doRotate();

    }

    private void doRotate() {
        MotorA motor = MotorA.getInstance();
        while (true) {
            motor.rotate();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here the Main program.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread a = new Thread(new ClassA());
        Thread b = new Thread(new ClassB());
        Thread c = new Thread(new ClassA());
        Thread d = new Thread(new ClassB());
        a.start();
        b.start();
        c.start();
        d.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Shared<T> {
    private T _data;
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

    public T getData() {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            return _data;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void setData(T _data) {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            this._data = _data;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Shared<Boolean> b = new Shared<Boolean>();
b.setData(true);

//other thread
while (b.getData()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This isn't doing anything an intrinsic lock doesn't. Unless I'm overlooking something in all the clutter?